# I want to install Windows 7 on a blank hdd on a partition called X:(instead of C:) Is it possible?

Tags: windows-7, installation, partitioning, drive-letter

I have a brand new PC with a blank HDD, and I want to install Windows on a partition called X: instead of C:. 
How can I perform this?

Comment: I am just curious why you want to do this?  is it just for looks or do you have other OS's on the same computer under different partitions?  I know you said blank, but what is the purpose?

Comment: I want to migrate some software on the C partition(from another PC) and I want to separate it from the OS. I cannot migrate it to a different partition without hassle(let's say D) and I also want to maintain backwards compatibility, in case I want to migrate everything back. I want the separation for easy data wiping on the C:, without Windows reinstall, and for easier backup of the whole partition instead of specific folders.

Comment: have you tried mapping a network drive and mapping the drive as `x:`??

Answer (score 1):

An ugly hack I have sometimes resorted to is create 23 **tiny partitions** before the destination partition. (Can be deleted afterwards.)

There are also tools that can change partition letters post-install (Powerquest **PartitionMagic**). That must be done as early as possible, because not all occurences of the drive letter in various files get corrected.

I have also edited the registry manually at times:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices**
, but tools are far superior.
If you endeavor that, turn off the swap file first, at least Windows XP crashes badly, if swap file is unavailable.

Comment: I'm 90% there, thanks to the idea you gave me. 1) install OS on C. 2) While OS Running, create an X: partition, install OS DVD and install it on X:. 3) using a partition software, delete C:, and move X: to the position of C:. 4) Fix BOOT/MBR/BCD. Currently, I'm at this step, trying to recreate the BOOTMGR manually, since it resided on C: which was deleted.

Comment: "Bootability" restoration happens very reliably if you convert the nonbooting installation into a primary partition with bootable flag on, and then install the same or newer Windows version in some small extended partition (which cannot be bootable). It will revive the bootability of the first Windows instance also, and can be deleted afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do it:

1. Create a 60GB partition on the blank HDD, install Windows 7 on it.
2. From within Windows 7, create another 60GB partition, assign Z: to it (Decided to go for Z: instead of X:).
3. Insert Windows 7 DVD and install again Windows 7 on Z: (This has to be performed while the OS is running).
4. Let it finish, it will boot from Z: but the bootmgr will remain on C:.
5. Use EasyBCD to move bootmgr from C: to Z:
6. Boot again in Windows from Z: and delete C:. You can safely do that now.
7. Use Easeus Partition Manager to move Z: partition at the beginning of the disk, for maximum speed.

Comment: this sounds a little like another answer I have seen somewhere..... ***cough*** (http://superuser.com/a/744715/162960) ***cough***  only more step by step and specific to your issue.

Comment: good answer though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the setup of Windows. You can try to use [DISM /Apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824910.aspx) to apply the install.wim to a different partition. Maybe this works.

Comment: I'll check into that. Can I change the letter after the installation?

Comment: You can't change it later without braking everything.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this would work but, I think you should give it a whack, install Windows once, then go to install it again, on another partition and see if it let's you specify the name of the new drive that will be created. you may only get a `d:` but it would still be similar to what you want enough that it might do what you need

---

You could actually take the empty hard drive and a couple of drives that already have an OS on them and hook them all up to the same motherboard.

the Drive lettering isn't really static to the OS.   if I plug in a hard drive using SATA to USB cable it comes up as drive `i:`

it would only be drive `c:` if you boot into Windows from that hard drive.

---

I am not sure that this answers your question, but hopefully it helps you to identify something that makes it easier to do what you want.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the letters are purely logical, and relative to an instance of Windows. So, the second install should still be `C:\` on the second partition.

Comment: if I have Windows installed on 2 Hard Drives and I boot into one hard drive's OS the other drive will not show up as `C:` depending on which SATA port it is plugged into on the Motherboard

Comment: Okay, that sounds like what I would expect. I am also expecting the "D" copy to show up as `C:` if it gets booted into.

Comment: @Louis it will, I imagine that the OP hasn't tried any of this yet.  drive `x:` will be a little tricky but if they just need a different drive letter than `c:` then this is going to work for them I think